# How to load a class function outside declaring class in Java Reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I am using java reflections API to load my functions dynamically from a variable.When i was calling the functions in the same class,the function calls were working.

Now i am trying to call functions outside the declaring class.This is the code i am using.

```
   package com.test.controller;
   try
   {
     Class cls = Class.forName("com.test.Actions");
     System.out.println("trying to get method name");
     java.lang.reflect.Method method=cls.getMethod(action,String.class,HttpServletRequest.class);
     System.out.println("got method name"+method);
     val=method.invoke(this, instInputText,request).toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

I am trying to acess a different class and the functions and i get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is because of this line `val=method.invoke(this, instInputText,request).toString();`.

You are passing `this` as an instance to the call, which means it will perform something like `this.method()`. Instead you need to create an instance of class `Actions` and use that in place of `this`.

Comment: replaced `this` in `method.invoke()` with `cls.newInstance()` and it is working.